# Get function parameters count

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm wondering if there is a way in C++11 to get the number of arguments of a function?

For example for the function `foo` I want `argCount` to be 3.

```
void foo(int a, int b, int c) {}

int main() {
  size_t argCount = MAGIC(foo);
}
```

Comment: For which purpose should that be good for?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, I know at least one application of this, in heavy metaprogramming

Comment: What is `MAGIC` supposed to return if there are several overloads that differ in number of arguments?

Comment: @BaummitAugen, supposed to return an error. The same way the error will be returned if you try to take an address of an overloaded function without context. Do not see this as a show stopper.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can get that information by using a variadic function template.

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename R, typename ... Types> constexpr size_t getArgumentCount( R(*f)(Types ...))
{
   return sizeof...(Types);
}

//----------------------------------    
// Test it out with a few functions.
//----------------------------------    

void foo(int a, int b, int c)
{
}

int bar()
{
   return 0;
}

int baz(double)
{
   return 0;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << getArgumentCount(foo) << std::endl;
    std::cout << getArgumentCount(bar) << std::endl;
    std::cout << getArgumentCount(baz) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
3
0
1
```

See it working at http://ideone.com/oqF8E8.

**Update**

Barry suggested use of:

```
template <typename R, typename ... Types> 
constexpr std::integral_constant<unsigned, sizeof ...(Types)> getArgumentCount( R(*f)(Types ...))
{
   return std::integral_constant<unsigned, sizeof ...(Types)>{};
}
```

With this, you can get the number of argument by using:

```
// Guaranteed to be evaluated at compile time
size_t count = decltype(getArgumentCount(foo))::value;
```

or

```
// Most likely evaluated at compile time
size_t count = getArgumentCount(foo).value;
```

Comment: Too complicated :) see my answer for a shorted example.

Comment: @SergeyA, thanks for the prod. It's now more simplified than your answer :)

Comment: So very much true! :) The only thing is, mine doesn't call a function, while yours does. You need to make yours constexpr, but this would still be no guarantee of it never being called - this is why I prefer my version. However, yours have simpler code.

Comment: @RSahu Prefer to just return an `integral_constant` than `size_t` (see Columbo's answer on the dupe)

Comment: @Barry, my understanding of `integral_constant` being used in the dupe is to simplify the implementation of `struct get_arity`. For a free function, such as I presented here, that won't add any extra value. Please let me know if I am missing something subtle.

Comment: @RSahu It adds extra value from the perspective of encoding the answer in a type. It's always easy to go type --> value, but keeping everything on the type level just makes metaprogramming easier. Plus, you can then just pass this into another function and overload on different arity.

Comment: @SergeyA, Yes, making the function a `constexpr` definitely makes sense, regardless of whether the compiler translates that into a compile time evaluation or a run time call.

Comment: @Barry, I still don't quite grasp the value of your suggestion. I'm going need some time to mull over it. Thanks for the input.

Comment: How can we make this work also for member functions ?

Comment: @MuhammetAliAsan, that's a good question. If that has not been asked in SO, please create a post and ask it. You can add a link to this post from your post, just to provide some context.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, it can be easily done:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>

template <class R, class... ARGS>
struct function_ripper {
    static constexpr size_t n_args = sizeof...(ARGS);
};


template <class R, class... ARGS>
auto constexpr make_ripper(R (ARGS...) ) {
  return function_ripper<R, ARGS...>();
}

void foo(int, double, const char*);

void check_args() {
  constexpr size_t foo_args = decltype(make_ripper(foo))::n_args;

  std::cout << "Foo has  " << foo_args << " arguments.\n";
}
```

Comment: Maybe do something like this: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/4NWT_N

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't really make sense for several reasons.

For starters, what would this really be good for? You might be looking for some sort of reflection, but that doesn't (yet) exist in C++.

The main reason this doesn't make sense, however, is overload sets:

```
void f(int);
void f(int, int);
std::cout << MAGIC(f); // what should this print??
```

Comment: There is a way to do this.

Comment: The fact you can do it doesn't mean it makes sense, however. But yes, you're correct.

Comment: It makes perfect sence in many applications of template metaprogramming.

Comment: Why say it makes no sense when you don't even know what the use case is? This is exactly what is required for binding stack based scripting language native calls, you need the argument count.